# How do I print 0,2,4,6,... in assembly language?

Tags: algorithm, assembly

I have an assignment from my comp. system org. subject and unfortunately I'm kind of new when it comes to assembly language. I'm supposed to write a program that displays the numbers 0,2,4,6,8,10 respectively. How would I go about this?

Maybe this'll answer my question: (Reactions please)

```
.model small
.stack 100H
.data
.code

call proc

mov cx,5

mov dx,0
L1:
mov bx,2
add dx,bx
mov ah,02h
loop L1
int 21
endp
```

Comment: What assembly language? There are many, do you mean x86?

Comment: sir im giving you an example of it...

.model proc
.stack 100H
.data
.call

main proc
call ace1
call ace2

mov cx, 10

call proc
L1:
mov dx, 41h
mov ah, 02h
inc dx,
loop L1
int 21h
endp

*sir this program displays A,B,C,D, and so on (a program like this sir, what do you call this one?)

Comment: yes sir, i am suppose to display the numbers 0,2,4,6,8,10 respectively

Comment: Don't fall asleep in class next time, brotha.

Comment: im using a textpad for running my program

Comment: Really, Textpad has an x86 emulator plug-in? That's news to me :-)

Comment: I don't think it ever gets that far, @abelenky, the 'call proc' looks like an infinite recursion.

Comment: @Oliver, at what number do you want to stop (if at all).

Comment: Stop calling me sir. My dad was sir, I'm just Pax.

Comment: ok pax ^_^ coz i don't know you, what if you're a professional man? that's why im always showing respect to everybody eventhough he/she's just a kid.

Comment: this semester is a lot of hell to me, i enrolled C++, VBPro, Assembly at the same time. I'm concentrating mostly on C++ and that's why maybe I can't relate too much on Assembly, sorry.

Comment: Oliver, it isn't usual (on the parts of the Internet that I'm used to) to call anyone 'sir'. If you want to be polite, then it's enough to say "please" and "thank you".

Comment: Just out of interest, Oliver, what's your nationality. Don't answer if you don't want to but the "sir" thing usually indicates Indian cultural sensitivities to me.

Comment: im a thai ^_^ and even people who are smaller to my position/status in life, i usually call them sir, i dont know but for me this is the way i show respect to others ^_^

Comment: -9, seriously? I mean, I could see -2 or -3, but this is ridiculous... I might have asked the same thing as an assembly language beginner. A lot of people may not know about the different kinds of assembly language and so on.

Comment: Oliver, please left-indent your lines of code by 4 whitespaces, in order to ensure that they're presented as separate lines.

Comment: @david: This is how voting works.

Comment: sorry but i just found today this website about helping hands programmers, sorry for many mistakes T_T

Comment: @David: I agree, -9 seems a little excessive. Specially from those that only seem to know there's more than 1 assembly language, but not enough to show some samples in ANY assembly language.

Comment: Oliver, your current sample has many of the same mistakes as your previous sample, which I responded to in my answer below.

Comment: People are starting to vote back up now that the question is being clarified and expanded. I've seen that sort of behavior before.

Comment: I've removed my down vote.  I am reassured by OP's willingness to participate, rather than ask-and-run.

Answer (score 5):

Go see your lecturer and/or tutor and ask for advice. That's what they're there for. You haven't given us anywhere *near* enough info to help you out.

Here's what I *think* your ABCD program should look like. I suggest you use it as a baseline to try to make a 0 2 4 ... version.

```
    model  proc
    .stack 100H
    .data
    .call

    main   proc

    mov    cx,10     ; 10 loops only.
    mov    dx,40h    ; start dx at 'A' - 1.
L1:
    inc    dx        ; move to next character.

    mov    ah,02h    ; int 21,02 is print character.
    int    21h

    loop   L1        ; loop until cx is 0

    mov    ax,4c00h  ; int 21,4c is exit with al holding exit code.
    int    21

    endp
```

When you've at least had a go at converting this, post the code and we'll critique what you've done.

If you're taught something, it never lasts but, if you learn something, it lasts forever (alcohol-addled braincells notwithstanding :-).

`Int 21` is the DOS interrupt which allows assembler programs to use various DOS functions. It's conceptually a huge switch statement based on the `AH` register which is why you'll see things like `Int 21 Fn 02`, which means execute `mov ah,2` followed by `int 21`.

`Int 21 Fn 02` will take the contents of `DL` and output that to the screen. So the sequence:

```
mov ah,02h
mov dl,41h
int 21h
```

will output the 'A' character (0x41).

Similarly, `Int 21 Fn 4c` will exit the current running process.

Comment: So I wrote something similar except I didn't know how to print to STDOUT. Care to explain a little more about mov ah,02h?

Comment: Esteban, the DOS API is (put something in the ah register to say what functionality you want) and then invoke int 21 (which is the DOS entrypoint). ah=2 is the function to write a character to stdout. For details, see Google for the DOS API e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS_API

Comment: I don't see cx getting decremented, so I don't understand why the loop exits. Please explain?

Comment: The loop command decrements cx and jumps to the label if it's non-zero; it's effectively "dec cx; jnz L1;" - see http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~herb/cs200w03/loops.htm - it's a ripoff of the old z80 instruction DJNZ (decrement and jump if not zero) - there's a blast from the past for you.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure your class gave you *some* education here.
Can you code enough assembly to print one or two numbers?
Can you code enough to calculate the numbers, even if you can't print them?

Post that much code, and you may find help here.

Otherwise, you're asking others to actually do your homework for you.

Comment: +1 for steering him the right direction and actually being helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Assembly language is a symbolic representation of the numeric machine codes and other constants needed to program a particular CPU (or architecture). So assembly language for Macs (most recently Intel's X86) is different from that used to on the iPhone - ARM.

Your teacher is also probably expecting you to realise the difference between the binary form of the number you will count with, and the ASCII format you will use to display to the screen.

Answer (score 3):

You do know there is more than one flavor of "Assembly Language."

Answer (score 2):

You can do it exactly like the program which prints A, B, C, D, etc.: except that instead of starting at 'A', start at '0; and instead of increasing by 1 each time (from 'A' to 'B'), increase by 2 (from '0' to '2').

After printing '0', '2', '4', '6', and '8', the next number that you want to print is '10'.

To print '10', you can print '1' followed by '0'. Or, instead of invoking `int 21` with `ah=2` (which prints one character at a time), you can set `ah=9` to print a string (set `ds:dx` to a block of memory which contains "`10$`").

---

Later you suggested the following solution and asked for criticism:

```
.model small
.stack 100H
.data
.code

main proc

call defineuser1
call defineuser2
mov cx,5

userdefine1 proc
L1:
mov dx,0
mov bx,2
add dx,bx
mov ah,02h
loop L1
int 21h
endp

userdefine2 proc
mov ah, 4ch
int 21h
userdefine2
endp
```

My criticisms are as follows:

- defineuser1 doesn't exist (I think you mean userdefine1)
- setting cx needs to be inside (not before) the procedure
- invoking int 21 needs to be inside (not outside) the loop
- you need special handling for "10" as I mentioned above
- There's a difference between `'0'` (the ASCII character/digit) and `0` (the number) ... you need to print the character/digit, not the number
- You need to learn to test your code (write it, step through it with debugger, and debug it), preferably before you post questions about it.

Comment: That would give 0 2 4 6 8 : < > and so on.

Comment: Thanks, I added to my answer; I didn't read the question fully.

Answer (score 0):

You would have a counter beginning at zero and repeatedly increment it by two, printing the result.

Comment: Until you get to infinity? :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
.model small
.stack 100H
.code
.data
var2 DB "10$"
main proc
    mov cx,4
    mov ax,0
    mov dl,al
    add dl,30h
    mov ah,02h
    int 21h
    mov ax,0
    var1:
   add ax,2
   mov dl,al
   add dl,30h
   mov bx,ax
   mov ah,2h
   int 21h
   mov ax,bx
   loop var1
   mov ax,@data
   mov ds,ax
   mov dx,offset var2
   mov ah,09h
   int  21h
   main endp
end main
```

I'm new in computer science and when i saw this question i just wanted to try it. I have managed in doing it and here is the code

Answer (score -2):

```
MOV AX, 0
MOV BX, 2

ADDLOOP:
ADD AX, BX
CMP AX, 10
JE DONE
JMP ADDLOOP

DONE:
```

Ok. That's my best attempt. Lots of details left out. I should also mention that I have no frigging clue how to print a char to the screen.

Like others have mentioned, you didn't specify which assembly language so I chose x86.

Finally, go talk to your instructors, they'll help you much more than we can.

Comment: +1 But FWIW, the original question did suggest to start at 0.

Comment: my problem is... how can i do the increment process from 0 to 2 is there some any code about it?

Comment: And I'll quickly add another hint that you're going to have to decide when to stop "JMP ADDLOOP"ing

Comment: This answers that problem btw...(you'll have to make it start at 0 tho).

Comment: so it'll be

mov ax, 0
mov bx, 2

addloop:
add ax, bx
jmp addloop 

?is it? T_T

Comment: Yes. So then you have to figure out how to exit the loop, and how to output the number.

Comment: @Everyone: Yeah, I recognize all of those. I just had to go put the kids in bed.

Answer (score -4):

Are you using a macro for the output?

should be something like...

```
        mov eax, 0
```

myloop:  cmp eax, 10
         jg done
         output macro eax
         add eax, 2
         jmp myloop
done:

of course that's for 8086 assembly.